# Unable to set liquid template for rails app model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

I'm working in a project where I would like to create widgets dynamically based on associations with customs queries and set liquid to customize the look and feel of the widgets. I was able to set liquid but when I try to iterate with a for loop I'm not able to get the values but if I call the object as string then I'm able to get it: `{"netsales"=>42410110.43}`

Model:

```rb
class Widget < Accpac::Sqlserver::Base
  validates :name, :description, :template, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :widget_queries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :queries, through: :widget_queries

  def to_liquid
    { 
      'query_list' => query_list
    }
  end

  def query_list
    @result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(queries.map(&:statement).join(""))
    @result.to_a.join("")
  end
end
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInUp">
      <div class="ibox">
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <div class="row">
            <%= Liquid::Template.parse(@widget.template).render('widget' => @widget) %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Widget template:

```
{% for q in widget.query_list %}
    {{ q.netsales }}
{% endfor %}

# Output blank
```

Answer (score 1):

To access a rails model object with liquid, you have to create drops for the specific model. Basically liquid lets users customize things and the drops are there to prevent users from doing funky stuff with your database.

You have to create drops for each model you want to make accessable through liquid. In your case it would be sth like this:

```
module Drops
  class WidgetDrop < Liquid::Drop
   
   def  initialize(widget)
    @widget = widget
   end

   def name
    @widget["name"]
   end

   ...

end
```

After creating the drop you can assign it to your template before parsing it:

```
template.assigns['widget'] = Drops::WidgetDrop.new(widget)
```